# Bootstrap 4: center h1 on bootstrap 4 NavBar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

currently i am practicing bootstrap and html, i am trying to center my `<h1>` on the navbar , i've tried a lot of ways, even with the css way it didn't work, so here is my image[image: screen]

for your reference, i used this code within my HTML,

but, it didn't work,

```
 <h1 class="nabar" id="nabar" href="#" style="color: #2c3e50; text-align:center;">e-ticket</h1>
```

my complete code

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded" style="background-color: #ecf0f1">

  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="background-color: #ecf0f1;">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <a class="nabar center-block" id="nabar" href="#" style="color: #2c3e50; text-align:center;">e-ticket</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color:#2c3e50;">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>


    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `flex: 1;` to your anchor element with the e-ticket text and that should work. Check this link for [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded" style="background-color: #ecf0f1">

  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="background-color: #ecf0f1;">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <a class="nabar center-block" id="nabar" href="#" style="color: #2c3e50; text-align:center; flex: 1;">e-ticket</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color:#2c3e50;">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>


    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `mx-auto`...

https://www.codeply.com/go/S2g7bPmHjN

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded" style="background-color: #ecf0f1">

    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" style="background-color: #ecf0f1;">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <h1 class="mx-auto"><a class="nabar" id="nabar" href="#" style="color: #2c3e50; text-align:center;">e-ticket</a></h1>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color:#2c3e50;">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using center-block class should work-

```
<a class="nabar center-block" id="nabar" href="#" style="color: #2c3e50; text-align:center;">e-ticket</a>
```

Please find the working demo here-
https://jsbin.com/quqususuda/edit?html,output

Comment: it didn't work either, thanks but, i've updated my question, please take a look

Comment: There is no center-block in BS 4